# How to end the loop using a method?

Tags: python

How to force to end the while loop  using method?

```
class Test(object):

  def start(self):
    while True:
      self.stop()

  def stop(self):
    return break

obj=Test()
obj.start()
```

Comment: Nice idea, but you can't return `break` in the Python

Answer (score 3):

You should keep a flag, and check that in the while loop.

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = False

    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            self.running = not self.stop()


    def stop(self):
        return True

obj=Test()
obj.start()
```

If you want to stop immidiately then you will need to call break:

```
def start(self):
    self.running = True
    while self.running:
        if self.stop():
            break;
        # do other stuff
```

Comment: Your second example will break on the first iteration. `self.stop` always returns `True` Your loop will never get to the `# do other stuff` line.

Comment: @That1Guy: In the example of the OP it would also break at the first iteration. I think this was only thought of as a simple example, in reality `stop()` would only return True if some criterion is met.

Comment: @luatorThat's a fair point.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achive this would be to raise and except a `StopIteration`. This will stop the loop immediately as opposed to RvdK's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30195236/369450) which will stop at the next iteration.

```
class Test(object):

  def start(self):
    try:
      while True:
        self.stop()
    except StopIteration:
      pass

  def stop(self):
    raise StopIteration()

obj = Test()
obj.start()
```

Comment: That's not what `StopIteration` is for...  OP would be better off just writing an `if self.stop(): break` line instead.

Comment: @Kevin You could use any exception or even a custom exception, but I think `StopIteration` indicates the intent the best.

Comment: Exceptions seem to me a bit overkill...

Comment: @RvdK It is, but that seems to be the python way if you have multiple nested loops (which is a slightly different scenario).

Comment: @RvdK While they are called exceptions, they may also be thought of as events or messages.

Comment: @cpburnz: for nested loops this is indeed the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test(object):

  def start(self):
    while not self.stop():
        pass

  def stop(self):
    return True

obj=Test()
obj.start()
```

or

```
class Test(object):

  def start(self):
    while True:
        if self.stop():
            break

  def stop(self):
    return True

obj=Test()
obj.start()
```

Comment: @TimCastelijns: In the example of the OP it would also break at the first iteration. I think this was only thought of as a simple example, in reality `stop()` would only return True if some criterion is met. However, this does not really answer the question, as I guess it was intended, that `stop()` is **not** used in the condition of the loop.

Comment: @TimCastelijns The loop isn't doing anything, though, and the question was how to end the loop.

Comment: @TimCastelijns But ok, I added an alternative.

Comment: Fair enough, I see your point